# Adding custom data to Addresspicker results

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to modify the [jQuery Addresspicker widget](http://xilinus.com/jquery-addresspicker/demos/index.html) so that it can return autocomplete results from an array of custom data in addition to the Google Maps Geocoder results. The goal is to enable users to search for either a shop name, which will then be centered on the map, or a street/city/region name, which will be shown as in the unmodified widget.

The problem is, I can't get the widget to save the custom data as its local/method variable. My guess is it has to do with closures and I've looked around for solutions, but so far am still in the dark.

The custom data array is set during widget init:

```
    var marker = createCustomDataArray();

var addresspicker = $( "#searchbox" ).addresspicker({
          mapOptions: {
            zoom: 17, 
            regionBias: "id",
            center: pos,    
            scrollwheel: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            componentRestrictions: { country: "id" },
            types: ['geocode']
          },
          elements: {
            map:      "#mapholder",
            lat:      "#lat",
            lng:      "#lng",
            locality: '#locality',
            country:  '#country'
          },
          customData: marker
        })
```

And here's the modified script:

```
$.widget( "ui.addresspicker", {
options: {
    appendAddressString: "",
    draggableMarker: true,
    regionBias: "id",
    mapOptions: {
        zoom: 12, 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-5, 106.84517200000005), 
        scrollwheel: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    },
    elements: {
        map: false,
        lat: false,
        lng: false,
        locality: false,
        country: false,
        type: false
    },
    customData: null
}, 

setCustomData: function(data) {
    this.customData = data;
    return 42;
},

_create: function() {
  this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  this.element.autocomplete({

    source: $.proxy(this._geocode, this),
    focus:  $.proxy(this._focusAddress, this),
    select: $.proxy(this._selectAddress, this)
  });

  this.lat      = $(this.options.elements.lat);
  this.lng      = $(this.options.elements.lng);
  this.locality = $(this.options.elements.locality);
  this.country  = $(this.options.elements.country);
  this.type     = $(this.options.elements.type);
  if (this.options.elements.map) {
    this.mapElement = $(this.options.elements.map);
    this._initMap();
  }
  this.setCustomData(this.options.customData);

},
```

Any ideas?